# Session content not being deleted with either session_destroy(); or unset

Tags: php, ajax, session

I've had this issue for a couple of days and I can't seem to fix it whatever I try.

There is a loginform that either redirects you to `/dashboard` or `/admin` depending on the data that is in the started session from my loginscript.

This is my structure:

```
index.php (contains header with connection.php and the html login form)
dashboard.php (contains header with connection.php and some irrelevant html)
admin.php (same as above)
header.php (at the top of all pages, has connection.php included at the first line).
connection.php (my connection script, with at the top line session_start();
login.php (my loginscript, this script is called with ajax so I have to add my entire connection class in here with session_start(); again at the top.
logout.php (my logout script, it kills the session and redirects to login page this is linked to in my header.php)
```

In my loginscript I have the following part:

```
if($userpassword == $getuser['password']){
    if($getuser['rights'] == '1'){
      $_SESSION['userdata']['user'] = 'Administrator';
            $_SESSION['userdata']['rights'] = '1';
            $_SESSION['userdata']['logo'] = 'assets/images/logo.png';
      $loginresult = array(
        'login_result' => 'success',
     );
      $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => 'admin',
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
    }else{
      $_SESSION['userdata']['user'] = $getuser['name'];
            $_SESSION['userdata']['rights'] = '0';
            $_SESSION['userdata']['logo'] = $sessionlogo;
      $loginresult = array(
        'login_result' => 'success',
     );
      $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => 'user',
     );
    echo json_encode($logindata);
    }
  }else{
    $logindata = array(
        'userdata' => '',
        'message' => 'Wachtwoord en gebruikersnaam komen niet overeen',
 );
echo json_encode($logindata);
}
```

In short: when a user logs in as admin they see the name `Administrator` and when they login with another account from my database, they see that particular name.

My logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['userdata']);
header("Location: http://website.nl/login");
die();
?>
```

I have also tried `session_destroy();` instead of `unset`

Now when I login with an admin for example, it works fine, but if I then logout and login with a user, I am redirected to the correct page but I still see the name `Administrator` even though I'm not? This works the other way around too.

So a session is set and filled with data, but on logging out and logging back in, that session is not replaced/deleted, it just keeps existing.

Why is that? The only thing that I can think of is my login.php that is called with ajax. It is the **only** place where another session_start(); is present, but if I remove it my loginscript doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Do you add any parameters when starting the session somewhere or is it always just a session_start() with nothing more ? Checking your session in the browser for example. Do you see two of them or just one?

Comment: No parameters, always just `session_start();` How can I check a session in my browser? If I google for more information on that I see you can only do that with cookies.

Comment: This might not be an actual session problem, but rather one with browser caching. What happens when you refresh using [f5] when you are on a page where you see such a “wrong” value?

Comment: @CBroe Still the same issue, even with a hard refresh (ctrl shift r). But I found where to view my sessions (what @Sourcey86 was talking about) and yes when I login I have two active sessions. One on domain `www.mysitename.nl` and one `mysitename.nl` so with www. and without. I wonder why that is.

Comment: I found the solution, in my script I redirected to www. but my logout script redirected to without www, apparently a session is stored for both. When I changed all to be equal my script works!

Comment: You can also work around that by specifying the cookie domain for the session cookie so that it “covers” subdomains automatically. http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain, http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php